# WebRTC— use TURN as a signaling server?

Tags: webrtc, turn

I have a situation in a WebRTC app where:

1. I want to use TURN in all cases— I don't need/want to support P2P.
2. Both participants are able to call an API to get credentials and a hostname to a TURN server.

Question: since the TURN server is already there to act as a data relay between participants, is it possible to also leverage it as a signaling server to exchange SDP offers?

It seems a little redundant to create a separate signaling channel for the clients when there is already a perfectly good TURN relay that exists between the two.

Is it possible to hardcode a simple SDP offer that will establish a data channel between the two, then use that data channel to upgrade the connection with video and audio offers?

Comment: You can certainly run a TURN server and a signalling server on the same machine, but signalling is business logic that you need to customise for your specific needs and rules, so you can't use standard TURN servers for that. Additionally, since TURN can use a whole lot of bandwidth and CPU, you probably don't want to conflate those two functions; TURN servers would typically need to be automatically scalable, signalling not so much.

Answer (score 2):

No. The TURN server is helping with creating relay ICE candidates (by opening a random UDP port).

You can't hardcode a simple SDP since the ice-ufrag/ice-pwd and DTLS fingerprint along with the candidates need to be signalled *before* the connection gets established.
What you can is to create a datachannel-only connection and then signal the SDP to upgrade to audio/video/data via it. https://webrtchacks.com/the-minimum-viable-sdp/ has some discussion around it but mind you that the source code is a bit dated.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing STUN with TURN? With TURN you are both communicating with a well-known host at a well-known port, right? You are never establishing a connection between peers— you both know the exact host and port you need to establish your connection.

Comment: TURN servers listen on a well-defined port (specified in the TURN url) but then open a random port on behalf of you. The other side then learns this port (and ip) through signaling. https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#turn has some more information.